# Why is VS delete the applicationname.exe.config file?

Tags: c#, configuration, configurationmanager

I've got a weird fact.

When launching in debug mode my project, visual studio erase my applicationname.exe.config file.

But if i launch it manually or i'm doing "launch without debugger" it's fine.

I don't have put an app.config file into the project (if i did it, it will be copied after each compile). So visual studio is erasing a "loose" file.

What should i do in order to avoid this ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe VS clears the entire bin directory when you do a rebuild. Not avoidable, you'll need to add the app.config (what is your reason not to?)

Comment: I'm editing the config into the application so i want to save it. I can use also an app.config file but i doesn't change a thing.

Comment: I find a way for not losing it by setting it to read-only (enough for debugging).